# Writing Kconfig for my Linux kernel module: How to check, on which CONFIG_ options my module depends?

Tags: linux-kernel

I write a Linux kernel module, and in my Kconfig file I need to add:

```
depends on ...
```

How to check, on which CONFIG_ options my module depends?

For example, my module is a custom USB HID driver.
I *guess* that it depends on `CONFIG_USB_HID`, but how do I make *sure* that I need it? How do I make *sure*, on which other CONFIG_ options my module depends?

Comment: Check functions you use in the module, and check on which configuration options their depends. Dependency could be in form of `#ifdef CONFIG_FOO` in the *header* where the function is *declared* or in the source where the function is *defined*. Note, that some functions are defined in any case, but without needed option their definitions just report an error.

Comment: When you integrate your module to the Linux kernel source tree it would be obvious since you have to provide a corresponding changes to certain *Kconfig* and *Makefile*. Other than that is also obvious since module is using internal API(s) which might be modularized.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your answer, it gave me a good start

Comment: @0andriy Thank you for your answer, I will think in this direction